# Passport.js local strategy but with custom identification parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm setting up a local authentication strategy for my web app and I am running into some problems with the way I intend to implement it.

I have read over Passport's docs and seen multiple examples, but I have not found any information on this specific problem I am having. So to start I know Passport looks for the default `req.body.username` and `req.body.password`. I also know that if these are not the names of the  keys you wish to pass, you can swap them using the first parameter of the `LocalStrategy` constructor like so: `new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'otherUsername', passwordField: 'otherPassword' }, (username, password, done) => { ... })`

My issue is in the way I pass the user's credentials. From my frontend I encrypt the user's username and password into a single object in the body(I know the body gets encrypted anyway, but it was one more level just for me), and then I was hoping to manipulate the data before passing that on to Passport.

So to recap, I send my credentials in the following format:

```
req.body.login = {username: '...', password: '...'}
```

and then decrypt the login object, and then pull the username/password properties out to pass to passport. Is this possible? I feel like it should be, and if not possible with the local strategy, could I implement with another custom strategy?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this, I managed to solve my problem by using LocalStrategy's `passReqToCallback`.

In your passport config, pass this in as your first parameter to LocalStrategy and update the first param of the callback to be req: `new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true }, (req, dummyUsername, dummyPassword, done) => { ... }`

You can now access the request object in that function, so in my case I used the encoded params I had passed as the things I was looking for.

Because Passport is still looking for a username and password in the body, I passed dummy values in from my frontend so Passport does not think credentials are missing.